# Linq To Entity does not support

Tags: c#, sorting, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, notsupportedexception

I am learning MVC and I am storing a user's Date of Birth to show his age. Data is saved properly. Then to sort the data I followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It works on First Name and Last Name but on sorting for age it throws exception 
*Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.*
My code for action is

```
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, int? page, string currentFilter, string q)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.FNSortParam = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder) ? "FName_Desc" : "";
        ViewBag.LNSortParam = sortOrder == "LName" ? "LN_Desc" : "LName";
        ViewBag.AgeSortParam = sortOrder == "Age" ? "Age_Desc" : "Age";
        var query = q;
        if (query != null)
            page = 1;
        else
            query = currentFilter;

        var users = db.MyAppUsers.Select(a => a);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        {
            var nQuery = query.ToUpper();
            users = users.Where(a => a.FName.ToUpper().Contains(nQuery) ||
              a.LName.ToUpper().Contains(nQuery) || a.Email.Contains(nQuery));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "FName_Desc":
                users = users.OrderByDescending(a => a.FName);
                break;
            case "LName":
                users = users.OrderBy(a => a.LName);
                break;
            case "LN_Desc":
                users = users.OrderByDescending(a => a.LName);
                break;
            case "Age":
                users = users.OrderBy(a => new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Subtract(a.DOB).Ticks));
                break;
            case "Age_Desc":
                users = users.OrderByDescending(a => new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Subtract(a.DOB).Ticks));
                break;
            default:
                users = users.OrderBy(a => a.FName);
                break;
        }
    //            public DateTime Age
    //{
    //    get { return new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DOB).Ticks); }
    //}

    int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

and for View is

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                var age = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(item.DOB).Ticks);
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => age.Year)
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>
                }
```

I can't figure it out. Can anybody help?

Comment: just use a.DOB, you don't need to count the actual age to do the sorting.

Comment: You cannot use a method in the query that way. But why is it not just `users = users.OrderBy(a => a.DOB);`?

Comment: I think it would sort by year in date of birth and I want to sort by age.

Comment: It will sort by the date, not the year of the date.

Comment: it will sort exactly at the value, well depending on what you had save but if you save month/day/year (any arrangement) it will be sort that way.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks a lot guys